# Use ellipsis in bootstrap table if number of characters exceeds 200

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'd like to hide the text if the number of characters in columns exceeds 200. I'd to apply this condition to all columns in my table.

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-show-fullscreen="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
  data-detail-view="true"
  data-show-export="true"
  data-click-to-select="true"
  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
  data-minimum-count-columns="2"
  data-show-pagination-switch="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-id-field="id"
  data-page-list="[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
  data-show-footer="true"
  data-response-handler="responseHandler">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="upload_date" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
      <th data-field="product_code" data-sortable="true">Code</th>
      <th data-field="Title" data-sortable="true">Title</th>
      <th data-field="Description" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need javascript

Comment: Are you using datatables here?

Comment: @thursday_dan yes, mysql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an example of this working using the `data-formatter` attribute provided by the Bootstrap Table plugin.

I defined a function that strips the text if it over a certain amount of characters.

You can find an example of this [here](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/UtechtDustin/6167).

Add this to the column you want to set a limit on:

```
data-formatter="shortingText"
```

Finally, create the formatted function required, and set the character limit to what you like.

```
function shortingText(value) {
    if(value.length <= 50) {
        return value;
    }
    
    return value.substring(0, 50) + '...';
 }
```

See [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/5537) for further reading.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for